# Grub only in shell mode, wrong root and prefix set

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gpt

I am dualbooting a Laptop with Windows 10 and PopOS using grub2.

The problem is that grub doesn't show the OS selection menu and instead just goes to the grub shell. How can i configure/install grub2 to show the selection menu automatically?

I can manually load the Grub menu as follows which then functions as expected, viewing popOS, advanced popOS, Windows, System Setup and even a custom "Shutdown" menuentry I configured in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.

```
grub>set prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub
grub>insmod normal
grub>normal
```

When inspecting the values grub loads up with, the problem seems to be that all paths point to the first partition (the windows bootloader) and and thus to nowhere.

The paths grub starts with are as follows:

```
cmdpath=(hd0,gpt1)
prefix=(hd0,gpt1)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt1
```

`gpt1` is the windows bootloader, so i presume it's looking for it's configuration and doesn't find it.

I tried reinstalling the grub packages, reinstalling grub, updating it and running the ubuntu boot-repair tool as recommended by various online-threads with similar issues (all separately):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall grub-common grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-efi-amd64 grub2-common
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub2
```

All of which worked and reported success but didn't change anything.

I also checked that in `/boot/efi/EFI/pop/grub.cfg` the correct values are set:

```
search.fs_uuid 1672afd3-3d1c-462d-9284-1f0d6b1e07e9 root hd0,gpt5 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

My Partition Layout (in German):

```
Festplatte  /dev/sda:  256GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/4096B
Partitionstabelle: gpt
Disk-Flags: 

Nummer  Anfang  Ende   Größe   Dateisystem  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      106MB   123MB  16,8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      123MB   202GB  202GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      202GB   256GB  53,2GB  ext4
 4      256GB   256GB  537MB   fat32                                      boot, esp
```

And I presume grub2 is in partition 4.

My UEFI shows 3 boot options, the windows bootloader, grub as ubuntu and just the harddrive which boots the grub-shell aswell.

Also Secure Boot is disabled, otherwise grub refuses to load the Kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently OP has already fixed their problem but for anyone still finding this:

I had a very similar problem where my `$prefix` variable was pointing to the wrong directory. I worked around it by moving the `grub.cfg` file to the path defined in `$prefix`. On pop-os that path is `/EFI/ubuntu` on the efi partition.

On the booted system enter this command into a terminal:

```
sudo cp -r /boot/efi/EFI/pop /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
```

or alternatively

```
sudo cp -r /boot/efi/grub /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
```

What this does:

When grub boots, it searches for a `grub.cfg` file at the defined path (`$prefix`). On pop-os this path is usually `/EFI/ubuntu` on the partition grub was loaded from. When you boot your system the efi partition automatically gets mounted to `/boot/efi`. So `/` for grub is the same as `/boot/efi/` for your os. Moving the file to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` enables grub to find it at the path `/EFI/ubuntu`.

I hope this makes sense. This is just how I understood it, I may be wrong.

Note: When i did `ls -la /` in grub it displayed the `EFI` folder as `efi`, which really confused me. But apparently grub does not really care about capitalization that much.

Comment: This is actually a good solution. But is it possible to symlink instead of copying, because the config file may be obsolete after an update?

Comment: @Awakened as far as i know grub doesn't support symlinks.
I'm not an expert tho

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured it out:

apparently my UEFI doesn't understand multiple EFI-Partitions on one Harddrive and defaulted to the one created by Windows, which, maybe because of an old ubuntu install, had grub on it.

To anyone finding this question with a similar problem: make sure that the boot-images you are booting is actually the one you want it to be. Do so by executing `set` in the grub shell and looking at the `cmdline` parameter. It tells you what partition was booted.