# Persistent fix to 'minimal BASH like line editing is supported'

Tags: boot, grub2

Yesterday I updated my OS version from Kubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, Unfortunately it came with a slew of problems (primarily with Grub 2.06)

Today, I encountered the following error upon booting Grub:

```
minimal BASH like line editing is supported (...).
```

Instead of being directed towards the usual graphical interface, I was presented with a CLI, asking me for input. I have, with success, temporarily solved the issue with advice given in on [this post at geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/).

by executing the following commands:

```
set root=(hd1,gpt2)
set prefix=(hd1,gpt2)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

and

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdXY (in my case, /boot/efi is located on sdb3)
sudo update-grub
```

upon booting my OS. However, upon rebooting the problem persists, and I am once again sent to the CLI.

Output from

```
sudo update-grub
```

is as follows:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-131-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-131-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-131-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-131-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb3@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-131-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-131-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb3@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
```

Output of `grub-install`:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Output of `df`

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            1629800      1972   1627828   1% /run
/dev/sdb2      205377444  77481204 117390824  40% /
tmpfs            8148984       512   8148472   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/sdb3         998480     37892    960588   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1      557135192 205411480 323349288  39% /media/User/Linux HDD
tmpfs            1629796        84   1629712   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb4      277079036  24608052 252470984   9% /media/User/Windows_10
/dev/sdc1      976758780 504811472 471947308  52% /media/User/Seagate
```

Output of `fdisk -l`

```
Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 1134323711 1134321664 540,9G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdb: 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: CT500MX500SSD1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9592ABCA-3C53-4225-B388-FDF8B09DF156

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2    1052672 420614143 419561472 200,1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  420614144 422615039   2000896   977M EFI System
/dev/sdb4  422615040 976773119 554158080 264,2G Microsoft basic data
```

How do I get past this?

Comment: With multiple disks, you likely have multiple EFI partitions, so the one you fixed, may not be the one you boot from.  Cut and paste the actual grub-install and the output. Include more information like df and the non-loop output of sudo fdisk -l

Comment: @ubfan1 There's only one EFI partition: on sdb3 for me. In any case, i added the requested outputs in the edit.

Comment: Track down the disconnect on grub finding its menus.  cat the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file, and compare the UUID there against the UUID of /dev/sdb2 (sudo blkid will list them).  They should match.  The configfile command then uses the UUID to import the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file for the grub menu -- does it exist?

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you! The issue is now solved. The problem indeed seemed to be the fact that /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg referenced the wrong partition (it pointed to /dev/sdb1, instead). Through the nano command i edited it to reflect the proper path (UUID and hdx/gptx), and now the GRUB menu loads as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Track down the disconnect on grub finding its menus. cat the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file, and compare the UUID there against the UUID of /dev/sdb2 (sudo blkid will list them). They should match. The configfile command then uses the UUID to import the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file for the grub menu -- does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pop os (or potentially other distros) like me, it appears that the partitions configured in `/boot/efi/EFI/pop/grub.cfg` did not match what i saw when i used `echo $prefix` and `echo $root`.

Turns out that GRUB defaults to the bun`/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` and if it doesn't exist somehow (got deleted or something), it uses some default values.

Short answer is to copy your distro's `grub.cfg` into the '/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg'

See [Grub only in shell mode, wrong root and prefix set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284787/grub-only-in-shell-mode-wrong-root-and-prefix-set)